# In The Walking Dead, if everyone is infected, why are the zombies trying to eat them and not other zombies?

Tags: the-walking-dead

If everyone is infected, why are the zombies trying to eat them and not other zombies?

Answer (score 6):

They try to eat fresh flesh. Being it infected or not is unimportant.

Comment: Well, no, because otherwise they would attack each other as well, wouldn't they?

Comment: There's a difference between being "infected" and being a "walker", right? The living's flesh might be infected, but it's still fresh until they die and rise as walkers, at which point the flesh rots rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone *is* infected, but not everyone has turned. Normal people have a normal scent, that zombies can smell and are attracted to. They don't (or can't) smell the rotten flesh of the people that have turned. That's why zombies only try to eat (fresh) humans and (fresh) animals and not each other.